# After installing, Addon should be upgraded to 2.8x

Tags: add-on

I have zero knowledge of programming. The problem I am facing is when installing addon it is showing to upgrade to 2.8x version.

Here's the part of the code. where one of the warnings is showed.

````
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(import_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(export_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(import_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(export_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(import_leveldefs)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(export_leveldefs)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(import_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(export_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(import_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(export_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(import_leveldefs)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(export_leveldefs)
```
````

Comment: Maybe an old addon for 2.7? Some of the addons werent updated by their designers for 2.8. You have to install addon that is made for the new 2.8 version... There is no direct update in blender if I know.

Comment: Yes, I know so I am sharing the code and trying if anyone can fix it.